# Delete conditional columns from a sparse matrix

Tags: python-3.x, sparse-matrix, tfidfvectorizer

To extract important features from a sparse matrix,I want to simply remove the columns whose mean score is less than some specified threshold. Considering the following example

```
import numpy as np
counts = [[3, 0, 1],
           [2, 0, 0],
           [3, 0, 0],
           [4, 0, 0],
           [3, 2, 0],
           [3, 0, 2]]
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
transformer = TfidfTransformer(smooth_idf=False)
tfidf = transformer.fit_transform(counts)
print (tfidf.toarray())
```

Now calculating the mean score of every feature

```
summarizer_mean = lambda x: np.mean(x, axis=0)

print(summarizer_mean(tfidf))
```

Mean Results are

```
[[ 0.81236766  0.14681658  02311266 ]]
```

How can I delete those columns whose mean score is less than some threshold say 0.23 in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use numpy array for counts

```
counts = np.array(
         [[3, 0, 1],
         [2, 0, 0],
         [3, 0, 0],
         [4, 0, 0],
         [3, 2, 0],
         [3, 0, 2]])
```

Then you can simply do this:

```
threshold = 0.23
means = np.array(summarizer_mean(tfidf)).squeeze()
counts[:, means > threshold]
```